# Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableDictionary' to type '[NSObject: AnyObject]' in coercion for google ios Analytics

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-analytics, swift3

I want to add google Analytics ios into my project but i got some problems when i tried to paste their code into my app like the code below.

```
var tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "rootPlayView")

var builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView()
tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Then i got an error like this

[image]

how can i fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

type conversion

[image: type conversion table]

**Swift 3**

**Screen Track**

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "Home")
tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as [AnyHashable : Any])
```

**Objective-C**

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
// Set the screen name on the tracker so that it is used in all hits sent from this screen.
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Home"];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView]  build]];
```

**Automatic Screen Tracking**

**Swift 3**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self!.screenName = "About Screen"
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.screenName = @"About Screen";
}
```

**event Track**

**Swift 3**

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker

tracker!.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("ui_action", action: "button_press", label: "menuButton", play: nil).build())
```

**Objective-C**

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_action"     // Event category (required)
    action:@"button_press"  // Event action (required)
    label:@"play"           
    value:nil] build]];
```

**or use**

```
weak var tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
// Set screen name on the tracker to be sent with all hits.
 tracker!.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "Home Screen")
// Send a screen view for "Home Screen".
// [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];   

// Previous V3 SDK versions.
tracker!.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build())

// SDK Version 3.08 and up.
// This event will also be sent with &cd=Home%20Screen.
tracker!.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("UX", action: "touch", label: "menuButton", value: nil).build())
// Clear the screen name field when we're done.
tracker!.set(kGAIScreenName, value: nil)
```

for more information see [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/migration)

example

try this

```
var builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as! [NSObject : AnyObject]
tracker.send(builder)
```

**for screen track**

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
tracker.set(kGAIDescription, value: "rootPlayView")
let builder: NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build()
tracker.send(builder as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

**for event Track**

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
let builder: NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory(
            "xxxx",
            action: "buttonclicked",
            label: "you pressed xxx button",
            value: nil).build()
tracker.send(builder as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Comment: any idea on swift 3?

Comment: tracker in this case is an optional and requires unwrapping.  This worked for me:  
   `if let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker{
      tracker.set(kGAIDescription, value: "rootPlayView")
      let builder: NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build()
      tracker.send(builder as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
    }`

Comment: @FuadKamal- can you update the answer, it is useful for others

Comment: This answer needs update. This is not Swift 3 version. At least not current one.

Answer (score 27):

*This answer has been updated for Swift 3*

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
let eventTracker: NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEvent( 
                withCategory: "SomeCategory",
                action: "SomeAction",
                label: "SomeLabel",
                value: nil).build()
tracker.send(eventTracker as [NSObject : AnyObject]!)
```

OR...

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
tracker.set(kGAIDescription, value: "ScreenViewName")
let eventTracker: NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build()
tracker.send(eventTracker as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Comment: It was going hell out have tried many ways, your answer help me a lot in Swift thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 8):

For GA 3.17.0 use:

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEvent(withCategory: category,
                                                     action: action,
                                                      label: nil,
                                                      value: nil).build()
tracker?.send(builder as [NSObject : AnyObject]!)
```

Note the `!` at the end of `[NSObject: AnyObject]!`.

Answer (score 0):

Small follow up on the amazing answers, in swift 3, the method is

```
let builder:NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEvent(withCategory: category, action: eventName, label: label, value: nil).build()
```