# What is the proper syntax for Google Analytics Exception tracking in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I'm trying to use Exception Tracking for my app in Google Analytics.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/exceptions

I am just trying to figure out the syntax for this in Swift (not super familiar with Obj-C):

```
@try {
    // Request some scores from the network.
    NSArray *highScores = [self getHighScoresFromCloud];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    // May return nil if a tracker has not already been initialized with a
    // property ID.
    id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder
        createExceptionWithDescription:@"Connection timout %d: %@", connectionError, errorDescription  // Exception description. May be truncated to 100 chars.
    withFatal:@NO] build]];  // isFatal (required). NO indicates non-fatal exception.
}
```

I have set up my tracker okay, and it is working fine saving other data to GA, it is just the syntax calling `createExceptionWithDescription()` in Swift that I'm not certain of.

There sure doesn't appear to be much in the way of examples / docs for using Swift for Google Analytics... =/  If you know of any, please let me know!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd imagine its something along the lines of:

```
let dictionaryToSend = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createExceptionWithDescription("Connection timeout \(connectionError): \(errorDescription)", withFatal: NSNumber(bool: false)).build()
```

If its a class function in Obj-C written like

`[GAIDictionaryBuilder createExceptionWithDescription:...]; // objc`

Its written like

`GAIDictionaryBuilder.createExceptionWithDescription(...); // swift`

Each of the colons in obj-c denotes an argument variable.

```
// Broken into two lines to make it easier to read
    [GAIDictionaryBuilder createExceptionWithDescription: @"String here"
                          withFatal: @NO];
```

You can do a similar thing in swift:

```
//Comma separated 
    GAIDictionaryBuilder.createExceptionWithDescription("Description String",
                                                        withFatal: NSNumber(bool:false));
```

I suggest you learn a little bit of the ObjC messaging syntax since a lot of iOS code is still in ObjC but don't worry a huge amount about it. Swift is a better language.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, David Wong, your post helped a lot to get me on the right track with the syntax.

This post also helped me a lot:
[Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableDictionary' to type '[NSObject: AnyObject]' in coercion for google ios Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561539/cannot-convert-value-of-type-nsmutabledictionary-to-type-nsobject-anyobject)

This is what ended up working for me:

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
let eventTracker: NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createExceptionWithDescription("No internet connection.", withFatal: false).build()
tracker.send(eventTracker as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Thanks again!