# Google Analytics GIA Tracker returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I Have integrate Google analytics for screen tracking to my app but at time of initlisation tracker return nil

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
```

I added sdk in my project and i have used previous code to init tracker any one have idea why this happens.

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561539/cannot-convert-value-of-type-nsmutabledictionary-to-type-nsobject-anyobject/33561673#33561673

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate, Add following code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
// Optional: configure GAI options.
GAI *gai = [GAI sharedInstance];
gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;  // report uncaught exceptions
```

Add these lines in view controller for screen tracking:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:name];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];
```